# What is the use case for a discrete measure in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-desktop

I'm learning Tableau and landed on [this page about the four possible combinations of field type](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/datafields_typesandroles.htm#possible-combinations-of-fields-in-tableau). I wonder what the use case is for a discrete measure.

To expand on my thoughts, [if Tableau creates column/row headers when it sees a discrete field](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/datafields_typesandroles.htm#discrete-fields-create-headers), I don't see how it makes sense to have an aggregated number (e.g., from SUM()) in a column/row header.

I'm just playing with my data, and I have AGE as a discrete measure. This field has age in years as a discrete measure, which I believe makes sense theoretically. Then I created something like this:[image] What's the point of having the means in the column headers?

I may be tripping and missing some really important use cases of discrete measures. But what are they if there is any?

Answer (score 0):

Not everything you'll make in tableau will be using continuous fields. Discrete fields are used all the time; this article [dives into the differences a bit more clearly](https://www.codingninjas.com/studio/library/discrete-fields-vs-continuous-fields-in-tableau) than the tableau documentation. But the main difference is:

> Categorical Representation: In Tableau, discrete fields are used to represent categorical or separate data. They are useful for variables that may be grouped, such as product categories, geographies, or customer segments.

As for the image you provided; you're on the right track but you put `AVG([AGE])` in the the ***Columns*** shelf, so Tableau took the average of the `[AGE]` field and separated as **columns** in your viz. I would suggest right clicking `[AGE]` in your data pane and [changing it to a dimension](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/datafields_typesandroles_convertdimtomeas.htm) rather than a measure (if it isn't already), and bringing `[AGE]` to your ***Rows*** shelf if you want to see this grid linearly, otherwise try swapping your rows and columns; `[GENDER]` to columns and `[AGE]` to rows.

Answer (score 0):

Whether a field is treated as discrete or continuous, only impacts how the values are presented visually - and has nothing to do with how the values are calculated.

Whether a field can be discrete or continuous depends on its data type. Dates, date-times and numeric fields can be treated as either discrete or continuous. Other data types can only be discrete.

The key idea is that values for a discrete field can be listed in some order (so the data type supports a less-than operator for sequencing values) while values for a continuous field can be shown as being some distance from each other, say along an axis (so the data type must support a difference operator)

So, on the row and column shelves, a discrete field presents marks in a sequence of row or columns, while a continuous field presents marks at points along an axis.

A field can sometimes be treated as discrete and sometimes treated as continuous depending on the presentation effect you are seeking. It's common for date fields to be treated as discrete in some contexts and continuous in others.

I keep saying "treated as" because what matters is whether the field is set to discrete or continuous when it is used on a shelf. The setting in the data pane is simply the default presentation style.

Again, the choice of discrete versus continuous is completely independent of the choice whether to treat a field as a dimension or measure.

Finally, to answer your question, a common use of a discrete measure is to display a value in a table.